# Cron reports error in php5-common job after update

Tags: debian, php

After an update to `php5-common` this night, cron reports a `sed` error "**invalid option -- 'z'**".

This problem has also been [reported on the Debian mailing list](http://www.mail-archive.com/debian-bugs-dist@lists.debian.org/msg1281679.html).

What should I do, until the problem is resolved through another update, to fix this issue in the meantime?

I fear that messing with the cron entry, that the package created, I could cause the next update to fail.

Comment: There's another update released (at least in Debian Wheezy) since this morning(!). Fixes it.

Comment: @artfulrobot: Ah, indeed, there's a `5.4.35-0+deb7u2`. I just loaded it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @artfulrobot pointed out in his comment, `5.4.35-0+deb7u2` was released, which fixes the issue. After installing it, everything went back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try the old statement in `/usr/lib/php5/sessionclean`?

*new:*

```
$ [ -x /usr/bin/lsof ] && /usr/bin/lsof -w -l +d "${1}" -F0 | \
    sed -zne "s/^n//p" | xargs -0i echo touch -c -h "'{}'"
```

*old:*

```
$ [ -x /usr/bin/lsof ] && /usr/bin/lsof -w -l +d "${1}" | \
    awk -- '{ if (NR > 1) { print $9; } }' | xargs -i touch -c {}
```